# Telebot with Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I work with the TeleBot library, everything works on the main machine, but when I downloaded the code on Heroku, it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
```

Code:

```py
import telebot
import token_for_bot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token_for_bot)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'HI')


bot.polling()
```

Comment: What's `token_for_bot`? Where does the token come from?

Comment: @Chris I import a token from a third-party file

Comment: Are you sure that the `token_for_bot` variable contains what you think it contains? It would be a Python module, not a string value. Please show us what's inside `token_for_bot.py` (but of course redact the actual token).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to execute this on Heroku console

```
pip3 uninstall telebot
```

then

```
pip3 install pytelegrambotapi --upgrade
```

However, do you use virtual environment and is there a file requirements.txt and Procfile ?